# Python - Read excel file from partial name

Tags: python

I'd like to know how to import a dataframe based on part of the file name

I have a file like: 'Report_Lineup_Export_20220809_1354.xls' where the numbers are de date and hour when you donwloaded the file.

I'm importing it like:

```
lineup_source = pd.read_excel('C:/Users/fernandom/OneDrive/08_Scripts/01_Python/Report_Lineup_Export_20220809_1354.xls')
```

I want my code to read whatever is in the folder that starts with 'Report_Lineup_Export', ignoring the last bit.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`glob`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html) module:

```
from glob import glob
import os
for filename in glob(os.path.join(_mydir, 'Report_Lineup_Export*.xlsx')):
    do_something_with_filename(filename)
```

Note that you can cut out `.xlsx` if you'd like to get all kind of files starting with that initial string.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to the above answer, you can do it with the [`pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) module in Python.

```py
from pathlib import Path
for file in Path('some/dir').glob('*.xlsx'):
    do_something(file)
```